# Constructing uri query string from user input for dreamfactory api

Tags: javascript, rest, input, uri, intel-xdk

So I have linked up a database full of content to the [dreamfactory](https://www.dreamfactory.com) rest api. The api does a great job at showing what URI I need to get the content I'm looking for. What I would like to do is construct this URI from user input.

Here is an example of a URI I need to create:

```
/rest/mydb/bp?filter=title%20LIKE%20%22%25tent%25%22
```

which is constructing this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM bp WHERE title LIKE "%tent%"
```

I would like to enter "tent" into an input box and construct the URI example given.

My ultimate end goal is to create a search app using Intel's XDK so I'm guessing I have to do this with JS, but I don't have a lot of front end experience.

Comment: pieced something together that is working, but really do not have much of a clue if this is the proper way to construct https://jsfiddle.net/YHjKm/5/

Comment: I don't know anything about dreamfactory, but by the criteria described your solution looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

Gues this does the trick

JS & HTML

```js
build.onclick = function() {
  var $search = document.getElementsByName("searchinput")[0].value;
  var $query = '/filter=title%20LIKE%20%22%25' + $search + '%25%22';
  output.firstChild.nodeValue = $query;
};
```

```html
<p id="output">&nbsp;</p>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="formValueId" name="searchinput" />
</form>
<button id="build">Build query</button>
```